# How to merge columns and rows in R, so that I can calculate the average number of moths per desired variable?

Tags: r, merge, average, wide-format-data

I am working on a dataset where I collected moths from trees in several fields. 3 of each tree type was sampled. In some cases, some fields were sampled on the same dates, but not always.

At each tree, samples were taken from the "top," "middle," and "bottom" sections. Because of this, there are 3 rows of values for each tree.

I would like to somehow merge those 3 rows into one, so that we can calculate what the average number of moths per tree was. I would like to do this for all combined species as well as for each separate species.

I am also curious to know how I would be able to calculate the average number of moths per each type of tree, and per each sample location (top, middle, bottom).

I am sure that this is probably an easy fix, but R is pretty new to me.  I have included a sample of the data below.  I condensed it so that it wouldn't be too large. I hope that I used the dput() function correctly, and that my questions make sense. Thank you all in advance!

```
treedata01 <- structure(list(Date = c("4/14/2023", "4/14/2023", "4/14/2023",

"4/14/2023", "4/14/2023", "4/14/2023", "4/14/2023", "4/14/2023",

"4/14/2023", "4/14/2023", "4/14/2023", "4/14/2023", "", "", "",

"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""),

Field = c("Field 3", "Field 3", "Field 3", "Field 3", "Field 3",

"Field 3", "Field 3", "Field 3", "Field 3", "Field 3", "Field 3",

"Field 3", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",

"", "", "", "", "", ""), TreeNumber = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L,

2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,

NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), TreeType = c("Oak",

"Oak", "Oak", "Oak", "Oak", "Oak", "Sycamore", "Sycamore",

"Sycamore", "Sycamore", "Sycamore", "Sycamore", "", "", "",

"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""

), TreeAge = c("Old", "Old", "Old", "Old", "Old", "Old",

"Old", "Old", "Old", "Old", "Old", "Old", "", "", "", "",

"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""),

Sample.Location = c("Top", "Middle", "Bottom", "Top", "Middle",

"Bottom", "Top", "Middle", "Bottom", "Top", "Middle", "Bottom",

"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",

"", "", ""), SpeciesA = c(80L, 1L, 50L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 10L,

13L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,

NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), SpeciesB = c(7L, 16L, 6L,

0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 11L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,

NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), SpeciesC = c(17L,

23L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, NA, NA,

NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA

), SpeciesD = c(19L, 5L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 13L, 15L, 78L, 0L,

0L, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,

NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,

-30L))
```

Someone recommended that my data was in the incorrect format, so they recommended that I try something like this:

```
# reformat?

treedata <- data1 %>% pivot_longer(cols = 7:10, names_to = "Species", values_to = "count")

#

treedata1$Species <- substr(treedata2$Species)
```

This is the code I tried, but I don't think it works with the way I have the data set up?

```
combined = treedata01|> 
  summarize(across(starts_with("Species"), sum), 
    .by = c("TreeType", "Sample Location", "Date")) |>
  summarize(across(starts_with("Species"), mean), .by = c("TreeType"))
```

I am not sure, but I guess I am expecting to make a column of the value for each sampled tree, and somehow take the average of collected species we would expect to find per tree, and so on? I think that my data is in the wide-format form.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were on the right track with `pivot_longer`. Applying it to your example data, we get this:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

treedata01 %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("Species"), 
               names_to = "Species")

# A tibble: 120 × 8
   Date      Field   TreeNumber TreeType TreeAge Sample.Location Species  value
   <chr>     <chr>        <int> <chr>    <chr>   <chr>           <chr>    <int>
 1 4/14/2023 Field 3          1 Oak      Old     Top             SpeciesA    80
 2 4/14/2023 Field 3          1 Oak      Old     Top             SpeciesB     7
 3 4/14/2023 Field 3          1 Oak      Old     Top             SpeciesC    17
 4 4/14/2023 Field 3          1 Oak      Old     Top             SpeciesD    19
 5 4/14/2023 Field 3          1 Oak      Old     Middle          SpeciesA     1
 6 4/14/2023 Field 3          1 Oak      Old     Middle          SpeciesB    16
 7 4/14/2023 Field 3          1 Oak      Old     Middle          SpeciesC    23
 8 4/14/2023 Field 3          1 Oak      Old     Middle          SpeciesD     5
 9 4/14/2023 Field 3          1 Oak      Old     Bottom          SpeciesA    50
10 4/14/2023 Field 3          1 Oak      Old     Bottom          SpeciesB     6  
# ℹ 110 more rows
```

Now, you say you want "average moths per tree", but perhaps you need to group on other variables too, such as `Date` or `Field` ? In any case, it's as simple as adding those variables to `dplyr::group_by()`.

So for example: average moths per tree by Date and Field, assuming that `TreeNumber` is a unique ID for a tree. In this code I omit rows with NA values:

```
treedata01 %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("Species"),
               names_to = "Species") %>% 
  group_by(Date, Field, TreeNumber, Species) %>% 
  summarise(meanVal = mean(value)) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 8 × 5
  Date      Field   TreeNumber Species  meanVal
  <chr>     <chr>        <int> <chr>      <dbl>
1 4/14/2023 Field 3          1 SpeciesA   27   
2 4/14/2023 Field 3          1 SpeciesB    7.83
3 4/14/2023 Field 3          1 SpeciesC    8.5 
4 4/14/2023 Field 3          1 SpeciesD   21.8 
5 4/14/2023 Field 3          2 SpeciesA    0   
6 4/14/2023 Field 3          2 SpeciesB    0   
7 4/14/2023 Field 3          2 SpeciesC    0   
8 4/14/2023 Field 3          2 SpeciesD    0
```

Comment: I am beginning to see now! Thank you!

I am sorry for my little knowledge. I will need to go back in and fix my data sheet. Unfortunately, tree number is not unique. It corresponds to the location in the field where the sample was taken, so for example, Trees 1 - 2 of a type on Date 1 in Field 3 were not the same as Tree 1 - 2 of the same type on Date 2 in Field 3, etc.

Also, if I wanted to give the average number of moths based on all sampled trees, would I need to make a sum column like the avg you created, and somehow calculate the overall average from all trees? 
Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you just experiment with and/or read about how `group_by` works, because that is the key thing here - you group on whatever combination of variables gives you the desired mean value.

Comment: OK, I see! Thank you very much! I will do this. Thank you again for the help with this!